# Error while converting the base64 string to the Uint8Array in Blazor Server application "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'location')

Tags: javascript, blazor, syncfusion, blazor-jsinterop

```
function BlazorOpenFile(filename, contentType, content) {
   // Create the URL
   const data = base64DecToArr(content);
   const file = new File([data], filename, { type: contentType });
   const exportUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
   let tab = window.open();
   tab.location.href = exportUrl;
}
```

When we create a pdf in syncfusion Blazor. We convert the base64 string to the Uint8Array to open/download the pdf. When the file size is large this conversion takes too much time and throws the following error.
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'location')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'location')

Is there any efficient approach that can be used here

Comment: This is JavaScript, not Blazor.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.